# How to not miss lines using equation enviroment

Tags: equations, environments, itemize

How can I stop the empty lines being put on - first between the itemization letter and the equation, and then between the two different equation

```
\item 
 \begin{equation} 
            \begin{split}
            g\circ f(x,y)&= g(f(x,y)) \\&=g(x,y) 
            \end{split} \nonumber
            \end{equation}
            \begin{align*} 
            g\circ f(x,y):\mathbb{R}&\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\ 
            (x,y)&\mapsto(x,y)
            \end{align*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Although most people understand your code snippet, it would be always nicer to provide a full (but minimal) code which is compilable. Like this we have to guess around and the volunteers have to type several lines of code just in order to have a look on the problem. I hope, my answer fits your real case.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using display math inside you itemization. An equation gets centred and adds space below and above. You should use inline-math here. For your section question. You can always add an `\vspace{-20pt}` or alike between the two equations, but I would recommend to set both formulae in one single alignment.

Maybe something like this?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item 
        $\begin{aligned}[t]
        &g\circ f(x,y) = g(f(x,y)) \\
        &\hphantom{g\circ f(x,y)}=g(x,y)\\ 
        &g\circ f(x,y):\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\quad\vee\quad(x,y)\mapsto(x,y)
        \end{aligned}$
    \item next item
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]